# Create a branch.io link and SMS it by parsing an existing referal

Tags: branch.io

My Branch.io is routing an invited user to my website. I get this hash data:

http://www.example.com/#r:179171121319449787

I am searching for a way to either:

1. Parse the JSON data of '179171121319449787' with the WebSDK and send a new SMS to user.
2. Forward the link with SMS.

My goal is simply to forward the information on and keep the cycle going:

Web invite -> SMS invite -> Mobile installation

**My SMS sending Branch.IO code:**

```
var linkData = {
        tags: [],
        channel: 'Website',
        feature: 'TextMeTheApp',
        data: {
            "foo": "bar"
        }
    };

    branch.sendSMS('+' + dialCode + phone, linkData, options, callback);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to use that flow, creating a Branch link (and not using the web sdk) will allow you to have folks who are invited through web land on our auto-generated desktop [deepview](https://dev.branch.io/recipes/deepviews/ios/), put their number in, and receive the data from the link they clicked on in the first step.

You wouldn't have a need for the web-sdk. If you wanted them to land on your website, you'd just need to use the init function of the web-sdk:

```
branch.init(
    "your-branch-key",
    {},
    function(err, data) {
        // data would contain those values from when someone clicks and lands. You could then invoke your SMS function.
    }
);
```